# change csrf token in spring-security

Tags: spring, spring-security, csrf

i am using csrf in spring security, like this

```
<http auto-config="false" >
    ...
    <csrf />
    ...
</http>
```

and put in every jsp page like this

```
<meta name="_csrf" content="${_csrf.token}" />
<meta name="_csrf_header" content="${_csrf.headerName}" />
```

The problem is that, every time I refresh the page, i want change the token. but as long as the user is logged in, the token does not change.

Comment: I'm curios, why do you want to change the token on every page refresh?

Comment: logged users may be planning attacks. Security in software is important to us.

Answer (score 0):

Spring default use per-session csrf, you could check [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/csrf/HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository.java) for its implementation.
Per change token, I recommend you implement your own . And call its method to reset token when you need to.